# Завершить thread

Tags: java, javafx, многопоточность

Есть кнопка `ToggleButton`, по нажатию должен из кода в отдельном потоке запускаться server фреймворка.
возможности завершить сервер нормально нет, отдельно в консоли он завершается через `Ctrl+C`.
Нужно, чтобы при активированной кнопке `ToggleButton` сервер работал, а при деактивированной (`selest=false`) поток завершался и переменная освобождалась для повторной активации.

Сейчас так, не работает

```
Thread threadTerminalServer;
boolean init = false;

@FXML
private void handleButtonTerminalServer(ActionEvent event) {
    if (init == false) {
        threadTerminalServer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                StartTerminalServer startTerminalServer = null;
                try {
                    if (buttonTerminalServer.isSelected()) {
                        startTerminalServer = new StartTerminalServer();
                        System.out.println("Start");
                        init = true;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    if (buttonTerminalServer.isSelected()) {
        threadTerminalServer.start();
    } else {
        System.out.println("Stop-1");
        threadTerminalServer.stop();
        init = false;
        threadTerminalServer = null;
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
    }
}
```

Comment: @hitman249 А жесткий `Thread.interrupt()` не пробовали?

Comment: @Barmaley, пробовал, не помогает, возможно что-то не так делал

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы похоже неправильно понимаете работу своего `Thread`'а `threadTerminalServer` - дело в том, что он сам прекращает работу после запуска вашего терминала. А терминал живет в своем треде и ему по барабану что произошло с его родителем.

Вам нужно найти способ убить тред терминала, а это вы не можете потому что у вас нет информации внутри чего живет терминал.

Я бы предложил такой способ:

1. Запускаем `Process.exec()` - фактически копию командного интерпретатора оси
2. Внутри него запускаем терминал (то есть мы теперь знаем внутри чего живет ваш терминал)
3. Далее, в случае надобности убиваем командный интерпретатор оси через `Process.destroy()`

Кратенький мануальчик как работать с `Process.exec()` [здесь](http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010016)

Answer (score 2):

Для таких целей просто создают булевский флаг и добавляют проверки этого флага в цикле, который выполняется потоком.

Comment: ну создам я флаг, завершить то как ? return-ом не получается

Comment: У тебя там вызывается конструктор StartTerminalServer, что из себя представляет этот класс? У тебя вся логика сервера размещена в его конструкторе? Или там создается еще один поток?

Comment: там, а дальше идёт сервер в котором я уже не могу ничего изменить ну и там дальше уже создаются другие потоки.

    public class StartTerminalServer {

    public StartTerminalServer() {
        try {
            System.setProperty("port", "7788");
            System.setProperty("jfx_use_udp", "true");
            TerminalServer.main(new String[]{});
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    }

Comment: Откуда взят класс TerminalServer?

Comment: из строки запуска в bat файле :)  
работает нормально, только завершить нормально не могу

Comment: >> из строки запуска в bat файле :)

wut?

У этого непонятного класса, вероятно, есть метод stop() или какой-то иной функционал, обеспечивающий возможность нормального завершения своих потоков.

Comment: может и есть, но спрятан он по самые простите гланды и видимо не в этом классе, т.к. я его пересмотрел уже вдоль и поперёк